# Why use cabal instead of make

Tags: haskell, makefile, cabal

As far as I understand cabal is the preferred way of building Haskell projects. Coming from a unix C/C++ background, I am used to make.

So what does cabal offer that I will not get from make?

Comment: I was going to make the mistake of mixing cabal with cabal-install, so I'll refrain from giving a complete answer, but does point 1 and 2 help you?

http://ivanmiljenovic.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/repeat-after-me-cabal-is-not-a-package-manager/

Comment: If you prefer `make`, you can tell Cabal to use it as the underlying build system - it's called [`build-type: Make`](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#more-complex-packages).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cabal will do more than just build your project, it also can manage your dependencies in a sandbox environment (as of 1.18), upload your package to hackage, and build libraries and executables in a lot less setup than it would take in make.  It's more similar to pip/distutils/virtualenv rather than just a build system.